# JS/Docker - Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, express-session

I'm trying to add `express-session` to my Node.js application which is running under the Docker.

Read a lot of posts:

[Express Session: Property 'signin' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'. (2339)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65130606/express-session-property-signin-does-not-exist-on-type-session-partialses)
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/49941
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/46861

I've tried to do a declaration merging of `Session` property, here is how my `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./src/types",
  "./node_modules/@types"
]
```

In my `src/types` folder I have `index.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'express-session' {
 interface Session {
    user: string;
  }
}
```

But when I run my project with `docker-compose up` command it gives me the following error:

```
/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:421
     return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
            ^
 TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
 src/routes/auth.ts(26,17): error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'.
 
     at createTSError (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:421:12
```

I don't think it is a Docker issue cause it happens during Node.js app boot.
Does anyone has any idea how this could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You should extend [SessionData](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-session/index.d.ts#L206) interface, NOT `Session`. There is no `Session` interface in the `index.d.ts` file of `@types/express-session`.

```
declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData {
    user: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue and have tried this, but ts-node still throws an error. tsc and ts-lint accept the declaration but for some reason ts-node does not.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the previous answer, that you have to extend the `SessionData` interface, you might use the `--files` flag for `ts-node`.
Described in this answer [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51666714/5341567). Right now it seems that `ts-node` doesn't take your `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the `express-session` types, (as of `@types/express-session@^1.17.4`), you need to add:

```
import "express-session"
```

to the top of your `d.ts` file: i.e:

```
import "express-session"; 

declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData {
    tenant: string
  }
}
```

Ensure also, as @slideshowp2 has said, that you are extending `SessionData` **not** `Session`